# Parsing Error. Unexpected Symbol '}'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

> Error:
>   Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(32,17): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol '}', expecting ';'
>   Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(54,1): error CS8025: Parsing error

This is my code:

```
void Update () 
{
    anim.SetBool ("Grounded",grounded);
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));

    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") < -0.1f)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1)
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0.1f)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: You will most likely need to put more effort into your question if you want people to respond and help. For example you could provide information on what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried.

Comment: You're missing some `;`. Voting to close as "typo".

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault thankyou very much :)

Comment: @JimAho Im sorry. newbie here :) Thankyou for that.

Comment: Np. When you get those parsing/unexpected symbols error don't focus on the line shown, the error is often multiple lines away from it. Just re-read each line of code and count your braces/brackets and double-check for missing semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at you code inside blocks after `if`, you'll that `transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1)` is not properly terminated. Try to add `;` after those lines

Answer (score 0):

The code already say you what to do.
At line 32 he expect the ; ( the semicolon sign ) add it at end of

```
 transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1)
```

and

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1)
```